# UIVisualEffectView and UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uivisualeffectview

I've put a UITableView into a UIVisualEffectView to achieve vibrancy. Everything works fine except for the bounce feature. The space where no cells are while scrolling gets drawn in some grey color instead of the blurred effect. I have tried to set all the background colours to clear but the blur still won't show. Is there any way to give the background the same effect as the rest of the table view?

[You can find the demo project here](http://thomasguenzel.com/downloads/TestTableView.zip)

[image: normal]
[image: scrolling]

Comment: You have some code to play around with?

Comment: @Jasper i have edited the question and added the demo project

Comment: Not sure why you add objective-c as tag when you are actually using swift

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm so used to working with ObjC and this is my second project using swift...

Answer (score 0):

set Clear color of  Table view, TableviewCell and ContainerView from Property. if not Clear then put code in your view Controller. also selection of cell none option.

[image]

**SWIFT**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

Comment: i did this, but unfortunately the cells are not the problem, it's the space where no cell is that's not showing the blur effect :/

Answer (score 0):

So I've found the answer. Instead of making the background a clear color, you need to set a white color.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```